# How do I stop R ggplot from displaying "a" as the symbol in my legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-text

Recently I made a plot using ggplot in R. When I add my code for ggplot_label_repel, suddenly the symbols in the legend change from circles into the letter "a".

Does this have something to do with wingdings font? How do I fix my legend?

I have made some example code with the reproducible error here:

```
#packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
#Creating an example data frame
years <- c(1990:1999)
population <- c(1:10)
df <- tibble(years,population)

#Adding random information to the df so that I can do coloring and labeling on my ggplot
df$group <- "low population"
df[8:10, 3] <- "high population"
df$status <- "highly endangered"
df$status[3:5] <- "endangered"
df$status[5:7] <- "threatened"
df$status[8:10] <- "recovered"

#The ggplot with the legend I want
ggplot(df, aes(years,population, color= group))+
  geom_point()

#The ggplot with the labeling I want but the wrong legend
ggplot(df, aes(years,population, color= group))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_label_repel(data=df %>% filter(group =="high population"),
                   aes(label= status))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: add `show.legend = FALSE` into `geom_label_repel` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add ,show.legend =F to geom_label_repel()

like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(years,population, color= group))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_label_repel(data=df %>% filter(group =="high population"),
                   aes(label= status),show.legend  = F)
```